How to retrieve optional claims when authenticating in Blazor App
I have set up authentication in Blazor using Microsoft Entra, and it works great. However, I need some more claims and have added three more in Entra:

But when I look at the users claims in the code, then they don't appear. I only get the 8 default claims. In my Program.cs I set authentication up like this:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
                string? instance = section["Instance"];
                ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(instance);
                options.Instance = instance;

                string? domain = section["Domain"];
                ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(domain);
                options.Domain = domain;

                string? tenantId = section["TenantId"];
                ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId);
                options.TenantId = tenantId;

                string? clientId = section["ClientId"];
                ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId);
                options.ClientId = clientId;

                string? callbackPath = section["CallbackPath"];
                ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(callbackPath);
                options.CallbackPath = callbackPath;
            });

I'm not very knowledgeable about authentication, but I think I'm supposed to supply scopes to my authentication, but I can find no way of doing this.

First of all, I can get the claim ctry in my test but I can't get the verified_primary_email claim. I'm afraid this is due to that my test user doesn't have value for this claim.

Here's what I did in my side. Firstly, we need to make sure that the claim do exsit in the id token or access token. Because the user claims are coming from the ID token, so that I test with Id token. I used this link(Azure AD auth code flow) to obtain the id token. Please use the redirect url you set in Azure AD Authentication blade.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id
&response_type=code id_token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=user.read openid offline_access
&state=12345
&nonce=abcde


Visiting the url in the browser will ask you to sign in, and then you will get the access token inside the url field. The url looks like below. Please copy and decode the id token. And you will see there's ctry claim.


Next let's integrate Azure AD into your application. You can ignore this step if you are already able to sign into your blazor server application with your microsoft account. If not, you can create a new blazor server application via VS but please select Authentication type as Microsoft identity platform. Then you just need to modify the appsettings.json with AAD properties. You can run the blazor server application now and your will be able to sign in with your microsoft account.

Next is to get the claims. Add codes below into Index.razor, and you will see the result.
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@using System.Security.Claims

<ul>
    @foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        <li>@claim.Type: @claim.Value</li>
    }
</ul>

@code{
    private IEnumerable<Claim> claims;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            claims = user.Claims;
        }

    }
}


